Laptop suddenly shuts down when opening or closing lid during sleep
I have a Lenovo laptop whose model name is ThinkBook 14 G6+ IMH, with an Intel Core Ultra 5 125H CPU and no additional graphic card. It has a pre-installed Windows 11 system which works fine.
I installed a dual-boot Linux system and it almost works fine, expect that when I close the lid to enter sleep mode (S2idle) and then open the lid, it suddenly shuts down at lid opening.
It can be successfully waken up by moving the mouse. Opening the lid after waking up is fine. If I manually put it into sleep and then close the lid, it also suddenly shuts down at lid closing.
The abrupt shutdown even temporarily turns off the indicator light next to the power cable port, which stays on during and after a normal shutdown, as long as the power cable is connected.
I tested Kubuntu 24.04, Ubuntu 24.04, Debian 12 (KDE), Manjaro (KDE) and Fedora 40 (KDE), and the symptoms are all the same.
I looked into BIOS and didn't find any relevant lid-related options. I tried switching to the S3 deep sleep mode in BIOS, and it didn't solve the problem.
I followed some other help and looked at /proc/acpi/wakeup, but I couldn't find the LID line which controls lid opening behavior. My old laptop works fine with Linux and it had the LID line. Updating BIOS and using the newest kernel (version 6.11) didn't help either.

If you want nothing to happen when you close the lid, meaning completely disabling the lid function, this is a known issue with many laptops running GNU/Linux systems.
I solved the problem by completely disabling the lid function, so when I open or close the lid, nothing happens—the laptop always stays on.
Edit and uncomment this lines in /etc/systemd/logind.conf
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

Do a reboot after you change it or sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.
Check this posts also:
Keep the PC in low power, but not sleeping
In my dualboot, KDE Neon(Ubuntu based) does not wake up after sleep/supend/closing lid manually, it needs to be started again manually 9/10 times
Edit:
Check this posts with the same problem:

Looks like the problem was with "ideapad_laptop" module. After blacklisting it, fn keys now work without crashing the system.

Lenovo notebook uses function keys to cause system shutdown
[Solved] ThinkBook 14+ Gen6 AMD resets when suspending with lid close

Troubleshooting

Many problems can be resolved with a driver and software update, followed by a reboot. If that doesn’t work, we have a wealth of help articles you can consult. You can also reach out to us directly.
ThinkBook 14 G6+ IMH Troubleshooting

Tested and works on: Thinkbook 2024 16+ IMH with Ubuntu 24.04 with kernel ...

This kernel module solves problem with laptop turning off after closing the lid
It seems that it's a BIOS/hardware setting that cannot be resolved through OS settings if you've tested different distributions and settings.
You either need to find a setting in the BIOS or downgrade or upgrade the BIOS if possible otherwise, there seem to be no other options available at the moment.

Blacklisting ideapad_laptop module solves the problem completely. I did it by editing a line in /etc/default/grub to be GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash module_blacklist=ideapad_laptop'. Will this affect the Windows system? Also, where does the ideapad_laptop module come from (e.g. BIOS)?

This change normally won't affect your windows system because the GRUB bootloader configuration and the blacklisted module only apply to your Linux environment. The ideapad_laptop module is part of the Linux kernel, and Windows doesn't interact with it.
The module it is included in the Linux kernel for handling certain power and hardware management features specific to Lenovo Ideapad models.
torvalds/linux|linux/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c
Lenovo IdeaPad laptop models offer a battery conservation mode 
ideapad_laptop module makes iwlwifi stop working
linux-kernel.vger.kernel.org archive mirror
